# Android: Keep multiple instances of an activity in the back stack

Tags: android-activity, android, android-lifecycle

I have an `Activity A` from which I start `Activity B`. In `Activity B` I want to start a new instances of B (with different contents), so that I can navigate back to different instances of B. For example:

> A -> B (with content x) -> B' (with content y) -back-> B (with content x)

**My problem:**

For an example navigation path:

> A -> B -> B' -> B''

when pressing back in B'' I return to A and not to B' as expected.
Doesn't android store instances of an activity in the back stack or do I have to do something to tell android to save every single instance so I can navigate between them?

Comment: Show us the Intent your using and your Activities in your AndroidManifest

Comment: Do not write any finish() after startactivity();

Comment: Did you get any solution? If yes, could you share the approach you followed ? Currently i am stuck in exactly the same scenario. I stored all the contents in shared preferences but, since i have large amount of data, using shared preferences also seems not feasible.

Answer (score 1):

You should read Google's [Tasks and Back Stack](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/tasks-and-back-stack.html) document.

Comment: Ok, it says "Because the activities in the back stack are never rearranged ... a new instance of that activity is created and pushed onto the stack (rather than bringing any previous instance of the activity to the top). As such, one activity in your application might be instantiated multiple times (even from different tasks). As such, if the user navigates backward using the Back button, each instance of the activity is revealed in the order they were opened (each with their own UI state)." But in my app, it doesn't reveal any instance. What am I doing wrong?